# Resources for how to retarget mingw like you can retarget GCC?

Tags: mingw-w64

I know you can retarget GCC (with difficulty), but I'm not sure if the same thing is possible with mingw.  I've found some excellent resources for how to retarget gcc itself, but I can't figure out if they apply to mingw's version, since none of GCC's  folder structure appears to be present in my install of mingw.  Is it even possible?  If so, can someone provide resources for me to get started?

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to use MinGW for this instead of installing full gcc under cygwin?  Someone more knowledgeable can give you a proper answer, but my impression is that the whole point of MinGW is to provide an environment specifically for building Win32 executables, so I woludn't be surprised if it can't build anything else.

Comment: That would make sense.  I sort of figured that if I was going to retarget GCC like that I might as well just do it on Linux.  But if it's basically windows specific (that is, if it's already retargetted to exactly one thing) then I guess GCC itself is my only option